# How to Render Action in view in C# MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview, renderaction

I want is to render the employee details of view page `ViewByDay.cshtml` in `SelectDaycshtml` page. Concept is to select days in a week from the dropdownlist and to retrieve information related to that day in `ViewByDay`. In order to do so I used `@Html.RenderAction("ViewByDay")` in `SelectDay`. But I get this error

> Procedure or function 'ViewByDay' expects parameter '@Days', which was not supplied.

Here are the code snippets of my view classes and the controllers:

**SelectDay.cshtml**

```
@model CrudMvc.Models.EmpInfoModels
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Select Employee By Days</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Days, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Days, (List < SelectListItem >)ViewBag.DayItems, new { @class = "form-control" })

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Days, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Select" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @{ Html.RenderAction("ViewByDay"); }
    // @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ViewByDay");}
    // @Html.Partial("_ViewByDay")
    // @Html.ActionLink("Get All Employee Details", "GetAllEmpDetails","Employee") *@
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**ViewByDay.cshtml**

```
@model IList<CrudMvc.Models.EmpInfoModels>
<div>
    <h4>ListEmpByDays</h4>
    <hr />
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Destination</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Days)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Destination)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "GetAllEmpDetails")</p>
```

**Controllers SelectDay and ViewByDay**

```
public ActionResult SelectDay()
{
    var days=  new List<SelectListItem>();
    days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Monday", Value = "Monday" });
    days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Tuesday", Value = "Tuesday" });
    days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Wednesday", Value = "Wednesday" });
    days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Thursday", Value = "Thursday" });
    days.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Friday", Value = "Friday" });
    ViewBag.DayItems = days;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectDay(string Days)
{           
    return RedirectToAction("ViewByDay", new {Days = Days});
}

public ActionResult ViewByDay(string days)
{
    EmpRepository EmpRepo = new EmpRepository();
    ModelState.Clear();
    var emps = EmpRepo.ViewByDay(days);
    return View(emps);
}
```

Comment: Remove `@{ Html.RenderAction("ViewByDay"); }` from `SelectDay.cshtml` - you have a form and you posting the value of `Days` and then redirecting to the `ViewByDay`method/view. Side note: `ModelState.Clear();` in the `ViewByDay()` method is pointless (there s nothing in `ModelState` to clear

Comment: Your code is not really making sense. If you want to display the table in the first view, then you want a form with `FormMethod.Get` and the `SelectDay()` method needs to have a parameter for `Days` (and you need to return the model). But you would get far better performance by using ajax to update the DOM based on the selected option

Comment: Dear friend. I suggest you read about partial views. Then use the same partial view in both ViewByDay and SelectDay. Otherwise I think Stefan Kert answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the displayDays as parameter

```
@Html.Action("ViewByDays", "Controllername", new {days="5"})
```

Probably the param days should be a integer.

You've already called it correctly in your method SelectDay

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectDay(string Days)
{           
    return RedirectToAction("ViewByDay", new {Days = Days});
}
```